# Detect if the iPhone is running a Debug/Distribution build at runtime

Tags: iphone

Is it possible **at runtime** to detect if the application that is running was compiled with debug or distribution.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Project Info, for a Debug configuration, add a Preprocessor Macro of "DEBUG" (in the GCC 4.2 - Preprocessing section).

In your code you can use #ifdef to see if DEBUG is defined if you want some code included or not for debug builds.  Or you can even set a variable (I can't imagine why you would want this):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  BOOL isBuiltDebug = YES;
#else
  BOOL isBuiltDebug = NO;
#endif
```

**EDIT:**  Well, another way is to define a boolean value in a Preprocessor Macro, ie: "DEBUG_BUILD=1" for the Debug configuration, and "DEBUG_BUILD=0" for the Release configuration.  Then you can use that value in your code:

```
if (DEBUG_BUILD) {
   ....
}
```

Just be careful not to use a macro name that could match a name that is already in your code or in any .h file that you might include either, because the preprocessor will replace it and it's a real pain to find those kinds of bugs.

Comment: The code is going to be part of a 3rd party dist and if possible would love to avoid #ifdef, but can live with it if there is no other solution.

Comment: I don't know another way other than using a preprocessor macro, but you can avoid the #ifdef, see my edit above.

Comment: How would you do that in swift?

Comment: @blackjacx [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24152730/1693173) explains how preprocessing macros can be used with Swift

Answer (score 4):

Without having to think about defining a custom preprocessor macro, you can just write a custom method like this one :

```
+ (BOOL) isInDebugMode
{
    #ifndef __OPTIMIZE__   // Debug Mode
        return YES;
    #else
        return NO;
    #endif
}
```

Or just write your code inline within those statements :

```
    #ifndef __OPTIMIZE__   // Debug Mode
       // Your debug mode code
    #else
        // Your release mode code
    #endif
```

The `__OPTIMIZE__` preprocessor setting in automatically set by the compiler regarding your project settings, so you don't have to worry about it.