# How to know if the iPad is using for development

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I wanted to know if there is way to determine if the device is being using for development or not. I want to enable some features on my app only when it is in development not when its is release to public.

Any help would be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2884391/310903

Comment: nope, UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM only lets you know if the device is an iPad or an iPhone (at present).

Comment: I am not trying to identify if its an ipad or iphone.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is not to know if the device can be used for development or not (a device that can be used for development can also download apps from the app-store e.g. final release versions). What I think you want to do is know at run-time if the build now running is a final release version (from app-store) or a debug version. See:

[Detect if the iPhone is running a Debug/Distribution build at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567838/detect-if-the-iphone-is-running-a-debug-distribution-build-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

I would not go the way you want to go because anyone can make their ipad a development one.  My personal ipad that I use for normal use is also used for development, meaning your app will behave differently if I am doing programming.  You may not want that.

Consider turning on features if the serial number matches yours.  Here is a library of [UIDevice extensions](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) that you can use to get your serial number.  The code is simple:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] serialNumber]
```

This returns a string, which can be compared to yours..

Comment: Apple will reject an app that uses most of those extensions, as many of them use undocumented/private APIs.

Comment: The main gist of your answer makes sense though.

Comment: @Jonathan: Which private APIs does it use for example?

Comment: Ok I did realise until you specified that other developers can also enable there iPad. +1 for that. Is this a private API?? I thinks I will go with your route if its not a private API

Comment: @Cthutu IOKit, for one. You can't get the device's serial number with *any* public API.