# Since there is no preprocressor in Swift, what replaces C macros?

Tags: cocoa, swift

Is there a way to do #define, #ifdef and the other powerful macros in Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [#ifdef replacement in swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift doesn't have a preprocessor and can't use C macros. There are some alternatives though.
For constants you can just use a let statement. For example:

```
let defaultHeight = 100
```

There is also some support for build configurations. They have this format.

```
#if build configuration && !build configuration
    statements
#elseif build configuration
    statements
#else
    statements
#endif
```

You can replace "build configuration" with the functions `os()` and `arch()` that return true or false. `os()` can take OSX or iOS as arguments while `arch()` can take x86_64, arm, arm64 and i386 as arguments.

You can see more about how Swift replaces C macros [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_21)

Answer (score 0):

> Simple Macros
>   Where you typically used the #define directive to define a primitive constant in C and Objective-C, in Swift you use a global constant instead. For example, the constant definition #define FADE_ANIMATION_DURATION 0.35 can be better expressed in Swift with let FADE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.35. Because simple constant-like macros map directly to Swift global variables, the compiler automatically imports simple macros defined in C and Objective-C source files

reference: Page 40, Simple Macros

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf