# Logtrace equivalent in Swift Language - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any logtrace equivalent in Swift language?

I do not wish to use the bridge-header concept.

The objective I'm trying to achieve is that I want println statements to write to console during dev/staging phase of the app and with the flip of a switch, console printing should be stopped just before pushing to app store.

On another thought-line, does println automatically stop printing on the console during distribution? (may be a bonus of migrating to Swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a similar approach as the built-in `assert()` function, which is
explained in the Swift blog:

- [Building assert() in Swift, Part 1: Lazy Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4)
- [Building assert() in Swift, Part 2: **FILE** and **LINE**](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15)

The `logTrace` function takes an "auto-closure" as the first argument:

```
func logTrace(message: @autoclosure () -> String, file: StaticString = __FILE__, line: UWord = __LINE__) {
        #if DEBUG
            let msg = message()
            println("\(file):\(line): \(msg)")
        #endif
}
```

Example usage:

```
let height = 13
logTrace ( "height = \(height)" )
// Output: /Users/.../main.swift:14: height = 13
```

To make this work you have to add "-DDEBUG" to the "Other Swift Flags" for the
debug configuration, compare

- [In absence of preprocessor macros, is there a way to define practical scheme specific flags at project level in Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111854/in-absence-of-preprocessor-macros-is-there-a-way-to-define-practical-scheme-spe).

[image]

The **advantage** of this method is that (as with `assert()`) the block is not
evaluated at all in the Release configuration, where "DEBUG" is not defined, e.g. in

```
logTrace ( someFunctionReturningAString() )
```

the function would not be called in the Release configuration, so any side-effects
or performance overhead is avoided.

---

Update for **Swift 2:**

```
func logTrace(@autoclosure message: () -> String, file: String = __FILE__, line: Int = __LINE__) {
    #if DEBUG
        let msg = message()
        print("\(file):\(line): \(msg)")
    #endif
}
```

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
func logTrace(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) {
    #if DEBUG
        let msg = message()
        print("\(file):\(line): \(msg)")
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Hi @Martin it seems in Swift 2, the __FILE__ and __LINE__ are not showing the caller file anymore - thoughts?

Comment: @hyouuu: That was a stupid error in the above code which is fixed now.