# Why isn't Swift compiler flag being set?

Tags: xcode, swift

I want some code to only be executed in a release build, but the code does not get executed when the scheme is configured to use the release configuration.

What am I missing?

I have the following in my app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
#if RELEASE
    Countly.sharedInstance().startOnCloudWithAppKey(appKey)
    Crittercism.enableWithAppID(appID)
    NSLog("crash logging enabled")
#endif
```

The target build settings look like this:
[image: screenshot of the Swift Compiler - Custom Flags section in Xcode]

And the scheme is configured to use the Release configuration when I run the app:
[image: Screenshot of release scheme configuration in Xcode]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set the preprocessor flags explicitly in the "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" section, "Other Swift Flags" line.

Please check-

[In absence of preprocessor macros, is there a way to define practical scheme specific flags at project level in Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111854/in-absence-of-preprocessor-macros-is-there-a-way-to-define-practical-scheme-spe)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Swift compiler ignores -D flags that assign a specific value. If you use -DDEBUG and -DRELEASE, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

now you need to set

```
Active Compilation Conditions
```

under Swift Compiler - Custom Flags

e.g.

Active Compilation Conditions  DEV

you can check

```
#if DEV
  print("DEV mode")
#else 
  print("PROD")
#endif
```

Comment: Can you please show a pic of this?