# Swift Xcode conditional precompilation

Tags: swift

I have a swift application, which I would like to package with a different configuration (compile time as a requirement)

I've tried setting Other Swift Flags = -D FEATURE_A_ENABLED
and in code:

```
#if FEATURE_A_ENABLED
  log("FEATURE_A IS ENABLED")
#endif
```

But nothing seems to work... any concrete sample, I've read 
[In absence of preprocessor macros, is there a way to define practical scheme specific flags at project level in Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111854/in-absence-of-preprocessor-macros-is-there-a-way-to-define-practical-scheme-spe)

But I don't want to ride on the build configuration variable RELEASE/DEBUG for now,
Is it possible to use a custom flag in Swift ? If so, what's the procedure if I want to inject the variable at compilation only, not via Xcode designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flag formatting is correct except that there shouldn't be a space between `-D` and `FEATURE_A_ENABLED`. It should be `-DFEATURE_A_ENABLED`.