# Conditional exclusion of code in Swift

Tags: swift, ifndef

I am trying to exclude some parts of a Swift file for a specific target. Yet I did not find any replacement of the #ifndef objective-c directive and moreover if I use a form of the kind:

```
#if taxi_coops
func pippo(){
    println("pippo");
}
#else
func triggerActiveLocationUpdate(entering:Bool){}
#endif
```

The preprocessor totally ignores the directive and tries to compile triggerActiveLocationUpdate. Please note the *#if taxi_coops* directive is respected in other parts of the same file.

Is there some way to simply exclude some pieces of code in Swift and/or why my fix does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In absence of preprocessor macros, is there a way to define practical scheme specific flags at project level in Xcode project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111854/in-absence-of-preprocessor-macros-is-there-a-way-to-define-practical-scheme-spe).

Comment: Btw, you have now asked quite a few questions and got answers to many of them. Please don't forget to *accept* answers that helped.

Comment: It may be a duplicate, as I said in other paces it worked, at last the if part. But in my code it does not work. Also I did not find anywhere how to express #ifndef.

Comment: Most questions I answered myself, and took care to report my findings. For the others I hope to cover all of them.

Comment: You can also accept your own answers to mark the problem as solved.

Comment: Sure, but in this case I have no answer myself, nor from other users.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue was about replicating the configuration in the **Other Swift Flags** file in the form

> -D option

Apparently Swift ignores the flags in the preprocessor field. Now it accepts ||, && and ! without any problem with syntax:

```
#if option || !option2
......
#elseif option3
......
#endif
```

Answer (score 20):

In Swift, use `#if !` as a replacement for `#ifndef`, e.g.:

```
#if !os(OSX)
    // compiled when not on OS X
#endif
```