# In iOS do we have something like Gradle Build Flavors on Android

Tags: android, ios, swift, gradle, build

In iOS do we have something like Gradle Build Flavors on Android.

Basically I want to integrate Applause SDK with my app but I dont want that code to be part of the release build. I only want to use applause sdk only to distribute the app internally and for bug reporting.

If there is nothing like flavors then what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make use of Schemes and Build configurations in Xcode. Here's the official documentation: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/customizing-the-build-schemes-for-a-project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/BasingBuildConfigurationsonConfigurationFiles.html)

After you create a build configuration, you should edit your scheme to use that build configuration. For that click on your scheme and select Edit Scheme.

[image]

In short, the process is:

1. Create a build configuration
2. Set some custom flags for that configuration. For this, go to your target, select Build Settings tab, and search for Preprocessor Macros. There you'll be able to add custom flags

[image]

3. Edit your scheme, or create a new scheme, to use your build configuration.
4. In your code, you'll have to ask if the flag is available using preprocessor macros:

```
    #ifdef APP_STORE
    //do something
    #endif
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this but it was not working, I had to add this  as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/24112024/2245895 and its working now, any idea why?

Comment: yup! because the example I gave was for Objective C. In swift, instead of changing Preprocessor Macros, you must change Other Swift Flags entry

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches you can take to build an iOS app in different flavors:

**Different versions of a resource file**

- Use a custom build variable to switch between different versions of a resource file. [This article](https://engineering.circle.com/different-app-icons-for-your-ios-beta-dev-and-release-builds-af4d209cdbfd) discusses how to build an app with different icons.
- For *.strings files and resources linked in *.storyboard files the suffixing approach suggested in the first item did not work for me. So I added a [*Run Script* build phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632301/where-is-the-run-script-and-build-phase-in-xcode-8) early in the pipeline. Using a script you are free to do whatever you want before the usual build chain handles your files. This is great for dynamic file generation or advanced file selection logic. As a switch you can (again) use a custom build variable.

**Modifiying code**

- Use a compiler flag as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24112024/89004). These can be checked using the preprocessor.
- Alternatively you can (again) check custom build variables. To make them accessible add them as a key in a plist file.