# Using Objective-C macros to access UIView frame measurements in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I have just started to shift from Obj-C to Swift in Xcode.

Is there no way to use macros from `#define` any more? I understand that I can use `let` to define constants instead, but I am used to having this set of macros at the top of most of my programs, for example:

```
    #define frameMinX CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)
    #define frameMinY CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)
    #define frameMidX CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
    #define frameMidY CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)
    #define frameMaxX CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)
    #define frameMaxY CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)

    #define frameMin CGPointMake(frameMinX, frameMinY)
    #define frameMid CGPointMake(frameMidX, frameMidY)
    #define frameMax CGPointMake(frameMaxX, frameMaxY)
```

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Ok - sorry about that. I'll start 2 new posts then

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291232/why-are-the-init-methods-inherited-from-a-class-not-suggested and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291203/how-do-swift-files-keep-the-privacy-which-the-h-and-m-files-did-in-obj-c now.

Comment: This may help people who are having the similar problems with shifting languages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111854/in-absence-of-preprocessor-macros-is-there-a-way-to-define-practical-scheme-spe/24112024#24112024.

Comment: Don't use macros, you are just setting yourself up for debugging pain later. Just write functions, at least you can step through them and debug them.

Comment: I'm afraid macros do have their uses sometimes which I miss a lot... for example, optional compiling for different platforms (iOS/OSX), or for different versions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `#define`s in Swift, but these all seem to be computations on the frame of a `UIView`, so you can extend `UIView` to add them as computed properties:

```
extension UIView {
    var frameMinX: CGFloat { return CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) }
    var frameMinY: CGFloat { return CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) }
    var frameMidX: CGFloat { return CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) }
    var frameMidY: CGFloat { return CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) }
    var frameMaxX: CGFloat { return CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) }
    var frameMaxY: CGFloat { return CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) }
    var frameMin: CGPoint  { return CGPointMake(frameMinX, frameMinY) }
    var frameMid: CGPoint  { return CGPointMake(frameMidX, frameMidY) }
    var frameMax: CGPoint  { return CGPointMake(frameMaxX, frameMaxY) }
}
```

---

#### Usage Example:

Inside of any subclass of `UIView`, you can use the properties just as you would  the macros:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    func demoProperties() {
        print(frameMinX)
        print(frameMax)
    }
}

let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 300))

view.demoProperties()
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 50.0
> (250.0, 400.0)
> ```

Comment: Thanks - that works for me! I also forgot you can now set functions as variables which is very useful (another way).