# Why are the init methods inherited from a class not 'suggested?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have just started to shift from Obj-C to Swift in Xcode.

I think I understand how the init() methods work now, but for some strange reason, convenience methods do not appear on the list of suggestions which I get when pressing `esc`.

For example, let's say I've created a class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {...}
```

When I am trying to write the line:

```
let scene = SKScene(size: ...)
```

It is suggested when I type `let scene = SKScene(s`, but when I try to write the line:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: ...)
```

It isn't suggested when I type `let scene = GameScene(s`. Why is this? I don't experience this problem in Obj-C.

Comment: This works for me Xcode 7.3.1.  Make sure you save the file where `GameScene` is defined.

Comment: Ok, thanks. @originaluser2 the code compiles and runs correctly when I type it in manually, though, so I'm sure initwithsize is inherited.

Comment: @vacawama I have Xcode 7.2 - that might explain a few things, perhaps.

Comment: @QuestionAsker Ah okay, I wasn't sure whether it was a pure auto-complete thing or not. I would definitely recommend updating to the latest version of Xcode – I also can't reproduce it on Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: Yep - updating fixed the problem. Thanks!