# Is Xcode 7 Debug Mode Working?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7-beta3

**Using Xcode 7 Beta 3**

The code below is failing to enter the `#if DEBUG` statement properly. I'm almost certain I'm in debug mode, but for some reason the following code isn't working:

```
#if DEBUG
    btnPrintPath.title! = "PrintPath"
#else
    btnPrintPath.title! = "" // EXECUTING THIS LINE.
#endif
```

My scheme looks like this:
[image: Build Scheme Configuration]

I'm running the app with `cmd + R`.

Am I configuring this improperly?

Comment: Did you do "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" -> "Other Swift Flags" -> `-D DEBUG`?

Comment: Wow, that did the job! It seems counterintuitive to have multiple areas where you can set DEBUG mode. Do you have Apple Documentation that you could post along with your comment in an answer? I'll select it if you would. @AaronBrager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-D DEBUG` to "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" -> "Other Swift Flags".

There's no official documentation that mentions this feature (you might want to file a radar for that) but I saw it used in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24397402/1445366).

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager. Here's another helpful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111854/in-absence-of-preprocessor-macros-is-there-a-way-to-define-practical-scheme-spe

Comment: Guys I can't find the "swift compiler - custom flags" things, where is it located?

Comment: Ok found it in the project options! Thanks guys