# Conditionally add commands to SwiftUI WindowGroup

Tags: swiftui

With macOS 12 Apple fixed the omission of „Continuity Camera“ in SwiftUI by introducing the command group `ImportFromDevicesCommands` which can simply be added to a window.

But when you try to use it in an app supporting **macOS 11 and 12**, you are missing the conditionality support as it is common when combining SwiftUI views.

I have tried the following:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ThrowAwayApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            if #available(macOS 12, *) {
                ImportFromDevicesCommands()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler brings up the following error message:

```
Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'CommandsBuilder'
```

I understand the `CommandsBuilder` does not support `buildIf()`, `buildEither(first:)` and `buildEither(second:)` and is therefore missing the `if`-block support as for SwiftUI views.

Is there a way to conditionally add commands to the `WindowGroup`?
Can I do some trickery with `@available`? (I'm really missing the `@unavailable`...)

Comment: This problem is gone with macOS 13. `if #available(macOS 12, *)` has been implemented there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution which allows me to check whether code is compiled for macOS 11 or macOS 12 by defining *derived* **User-Defined build configuration** in Xcodes project settings:

```
TARGET_MAJOR = $(SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS:upper)$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:base)
```

And then referring to this variable in the **Other Swift Flags**

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = -DTARGET_$(TARGET_MAJOR)
```

Afterwards I can conditionally compile code for macOS 12 by using:

```swift
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
}
.commands {
#if TARGET_MACOSX12
    ImportFromDevicesCommands()
#elseif TARGET_MACOSX11
    #warning("ImportFromDevicesCommands not implemented")
#endif
}
```

Comment: See also my answer which applies to cross-platform conditional compilation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369272/swift-ios-deployment-target-command-line-flag/71099967#71099967

Comment: It's really disappointing we have to jump through so many hoops just to support older iOS versions, especially when availability is built into result builders as a special case (`buildLimitedAvailability`)!