# How to identify if Swift was compiled with Optimization

Tags: xcode, swift

As some of you may be aware when running in fully Debug-Mode swift can be terribly slow.  Is there a way i can print out a message in code or to the GUI to let me know if I somehow forgot to compile it correctly.  I'm running in mixed mode so if somebody can give me Objc and Swift code that would be super awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can detect this at runtime, but you can use the `DEBUG` preprocessor macro (in Objective-C) that is defined in the Debug configuration by default:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"I'm in debug mode!");
#endif
```

This assumes that you don't compile without optimizations in the Release configuration :-)

If you want to check that in Swift, you need to define a [Build Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_23) by adding `-D DEBUG` to "Other Swift Flags" **for the Debug configuration only** in the Build settings. Then you can check for that configuration if `#if`:

```
#if DEBUG
println("I'm in debug mode!")
#endif
```

Comment: So now way at runtime to figure out what level of optimization was used?

Comment: @jeef use this technique to set a flag, and then you can check the flag at runtime

Comment: If somebody wonders why these flags aren't working make sure Xcode shows them in the order @jou specified them here -D DEBUG. If Xcode shows DEBUG -D it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcode's schemes to add a flag as an argument or in the environment variables - you can then check for it using `NSProcessInfo` - either `-arguments` or `-environment`.

In Xcode, go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme in the menu bar, select Run and under the Arguments tab, add either the argument or environment variable.