# Xcode: Swift - How do I declare a variable/constant with different values depending on the execution environment?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, swift, release

I am trying to figure out how to handle variables/constants for different environments, e.g. development(or debug) and release. For instance when executing a unit test the url for a web service should point to the localhost, but in the final product it should point to the public api host.

I have read something about setting the Swift Compiler - Custom Flags Debug settings to `-DDEBUG` and then in the code declare the variable like so:

```
#if DEBUG
  let url = "http://localhost"
#else
  let url = "https://api.example.com"
#endif
```

But that didn't work. When running a unit test the url is never set to `http://localhost`. Did I miss something here?

Comment: See this post will help you [link][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language

Comment: Thanks, working now. The solution was `-D DEBUG` with a space.

Answer (score 3):

Edit project scheme...

[image]

Define your environment variable:
[image]

And finally check if was defined for the schema that you are dealing with:

```
var baseURL:String{
    get{
        if let _ = ProcessInfo().environment["LOCAL_MOCK_SERVER"]{
            return "http:/localhost:3000"
        } else{
            return "https://api.fixer.io"
        }

    }
}
```