# how to use schemes to change color of a ui element? (Xcode, swift)

Tags: ios, swift, configuration, uilabel

I've got five different schemes: Debug, Release, Staging, Production, Testing. I've already set them all up.

I want to change the text of a label and the background color of a view according to the specified schemes.

In `AppDelegate` I've implemented the following method:

```
func setDomainEnv() {
        #if Debug
            serverEndPointURL = "www.debug.com"
            var fancyBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.007, saturation: 0.589, brightness: 0.572, alpha: 1.0)
        #elseif Testing
            serverEndPointURL = "www.testing.com"
            var fancyBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue:0.971, saturation:0.715, brightness:1, alpha:1)
        #elseif Staging
            serverEndPointURL = "www.staging.com"
            var fancyBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.373, saturation: 0.602, brightness: 0.863, alpha: 1.0)
        #elseif Release
            serverEndPointURL = "www.release.com"
            var fancyBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.571, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        #elseif Production
            serverEndPointURL = "www.production.com"
            var fancyBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.66, saturation: 0.516, brightness: 0.871, alpha: 1.0)
        #endif
    }
```

The method gets called in the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.setDomainEnv()
        return true
    }
```

I've also set up a file called `Constants` which stores my variables:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var serverEndPointURL = "www.apple.com"
var fancyBackgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

In my `ViewController`, I use those variables in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text = serverEndPointURL
    self.view.backgroundColor = fancyBackgroundColor
}
```

**However, the only thing that changes is the text of the label. The background color does not change based on the specified scheme.** It is always black (the value stored in the `Constants` file). it will not change based on the selected scheme. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you declare `Production`, `Release` and so on in the Environment Variables (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131865/xcode-swift-how-do-i-declare-a-variable-constant-with-different-values-depend) ?

Comment: Did you add breakpoint in `setDomainEnv()` to see if any of the `#if`s gets triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a new variable fancyBackgroundColor instead of changing the value of the already existing fancyBackgroundColor in the constant file. You should remove the var keyword in setDomainEnv method.