# Mac OSX Core Data App - keep Production data separate from debug data

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data

I have created a Mac OSX Core Data business app. My issue is that whether I am running the app in Debug mode via Xcode or running my own personal production version (from the Mac App Store), both use the same data (i.e. the same sandbox area). I need to be able to mess with the Debug version data without affecting my production copy. Is there a Project Setting I can use to change the debug sandbox location, or at the very least change the data location?

Answer (score 0):

I have separated my Live/Debug data in the code, specifically in AppDelegate.swift/applicationDocumentsDirectory, by changing the directory used when in Debug mode.

I used the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language) to differentiate between a DEBUG & RELEASE build.

I first set the DEBUG and RELEASE symbols here under Swift Compiler - Custom Flags: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQTN6.png)

Then in the code I return the data directory based on the DEBUG symbol:

```
#if DEBUG
        return appSupportURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("com.MyCompany.AppName.Debug")
    #else
        return appSupportURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("com.MyCompany.AppName")
    #endif
```