# Released Mac Catalyst app uses wrong Core Data database

Tags: xcode, core-data, app-store, icloud, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I released an iOS + Mac Catalyst app that uses Core Data and NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.

No issues for the users, but something is wrong **for me** when installing the app from the Mac App Store: it not only **uses the development database instead of the production database, but also merged both** (I think it loaded the dev one from local storage and imported the prod one from iCloud).

I once had something similar on iOS too but it was easy to fix: delete the app installed by Xcode or TestFlight, then install via App Store.

However, I can't find a solution for macOS. I've deleted the app's folder in ~/Library/Containers and deleted the app from /Applications but after re-installing from the App Store, it happens again.

What can I do to fix this?

Note that I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35928831/14544835) but it's not exactly the same - in my case the *released* app is using the *development* database instead of the *production* database on macOS, so I can't do the "if DEBUG" thing (unless I first clean everything maybe and do this for the next version?).