# Show debug messages if argument is set

Tags: ios, swift

In my project i'm showing debug messages with global variable:

```
struct GVariables {
    static let debug = false
}


if GVariables.debug {
    print("Debug mode enabled")
}
```

But is it possible to set argument here:

[image]

and check debug argument in code. How can i do this ? And is this a correct way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to those launch arguments and environment variables via [`NSProcessInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/)

```
if NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments["DEBUGRPM"] ...
```

That's not unreasonable and allows you to change the behavior of a compiled app which can be useful in some cases. It does however have some overhead since you're always performing this check. If you would only ever enable debug logging in a debug build then setting a value in "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" (as shown in the question @Larme linked) and using an `#if DEBUGRPM` expression will give you conditionally compiled code, saving the app the work of performing a runtime `if` test.

Which approach is more reasonable for you will depend on how you plan to use and when you plan to toggle this behavior.