# Environment variables and arguments passed on launch are not working once I compile the app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The thing is that I set some defaults before I run the app under specific target:

[image]

This is how I check if my target runs or not:

```
if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("DIFF") {}
```

or

```
if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment["DIFF"] != nil {}
```

but they works only after I compile the app on device. Once I close the app, and run again from the icon app on device, it doesnt work anymore. Why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those arguments are only passed to the app when it is launched by Xcode using your scheme. When the app is launched by the user tapping the the icon, the arguments will not be passed.

Documentation for [Specify Launch Arguments and Environment Variables](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/customizing-the-build-schemes-for-a-project#Specify-Launch-Arguments-and-Environment-Variables)

Comment: I need to make it working every time. What should I do then?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. You could just remove your if statement if you want the code to always run.

Comment: No, I have two targets. This code need to be executed everytime FOR THAT TARGET, even when I run the app from the app icon.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear that you wanted it to change based on the target. You'll want to add a preprocess macro in the build settings for each target, the documentation for [Build Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID34) or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24152730/385017 should help.

Comment: @CleverError Is there a documentation or reference on this? -Thanks

Comment: @CraigSiemens Is there any public documentation by apple confirming what you said?

Comment: @benrudhart I added a link to the documentation I could find.