# How to add developer-specific code in swift?

Tags: swift, preprocessor-directive, project-settings

I want to add a code which will be executed only for me (not for other developers on project) in swift project. In Objective-c it I can achieve this by
adding preprocessor macro

```
DEVELOPER_NAME=${USER}
```

and use it in code like this:

```
#if DEVELOPER_NAME == johndoe
  mail = @"john@mail.com"
#end
```

But it doesn't work in swift.
So how I can access in swift ${USER} value and other project settings?

Note: Question is different from
[#ifdef replacement in the Swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language)

I know that #if macro is available in swift. But comparison with some text value as

```
#if DEVELOPER_NAME == johndoe
```

doesn't work

Comment: @AaronBrager no question is different please see update.

Comment: @Vladimir I think you want to use an environment variable as JAL suggested…