# Uploading multiple builds of same iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to upload two build of same app with little UI changes on app store with different account. Can I upload the builds?

I have an app with multiple client so I want to upload builds for each client with their own account. I have modified the UI for each clients.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. What I do in similar situations is that I use one project for that (as you already have). And then I crate a copy of a target, so that I can customise it (custom logo, custom icon, ...).

To apply customisation in code I take advantage of "Custom Build Configurations". Here on SO I've described how I do this (as of writing it's the third answer to the question) [custom Build Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36502874/4502544)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, just make sure that the bundle identifier is different.

Comment: Any other things to do while creating app space in app store.

Comment: I assume this should be a question^^
The two builds of your app have a different bundleIdentifier, different code-signing. Maybe a different push cert. (Depends on if you use push)

Comment: I asked the question about to apple rejection or approval. I know same project with diff code signing and bundle identifier are treated diff builds.

Answer (score 1):

No issues in doing that. Just take care of the following things which must be different:

1. Logo
2. Bundle Identifier (as suggested by Fabio)
3. package ids of in app purchase items, if any
4. App preview images/videos
5. If you are using iAds for showing ads in your app, make sure you do not use the same provider account.