# Swift package manager conditional compile not respecting flags

Tags: swift-package-manager

I have a Package.swift file with the following structure

```
var package = Package(
  name: "MyProject",
  targets: [
    Target(name: "MyProject")
  ],
  dependencies: [],
  exclude: ["Exclude"]
)

#if DEBUG
  package.dependencies.append(Package.Dependency.Package(url: "Dependency-One.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 0))
#else
  package.dependencies.append(Package.Dependency.Package(url: "Dependency-Two.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 0))
#endif
```

When I build this with any of the following:

```
swift build
swift build -c release
swift build -c debug
swift build -c RELEASE
swift build -c DEBUG
```

It still always downloads Dependency-Two.git. This remains true if I prepend all of the above with

```
rm -rf .build/ && rm -rf Packages/
```

So I don't think it's because it's reusing some cache. Is it possible to do what I'm intending here?

Comment: What about `if getenv("SOME_KEY") != nil { /* add some dependency */ }`? And invoke the build command as `SOME_KEY=true swift build -c debug`. Whether `Package.swift` is conditionally compiled or conditionally executed has the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. The manifest is not intended to be used to declare conditional behaviors in this manner, but unfortunately for what you are trying to do, the mechanism by which this *would* be supported (e.g., including additional APIs from `PackageDescription` to declare what you want in each configuration) is not designed yet.

I suggest you file an enhancement request for this feature on https://bugs.swift.org.

Answer (score 4):

Still not available. My workaround has been to create multiple Package.swift files, named like `Package-DEBUG.swift` and have a script copy the appropriate one to `Package.swift` at build time.

This is a really mindless workaround and the SPM developers really need to implement command-line flags.

Answer (score 0):

It's not super ideal but you could check environment variables, like the [SwiftSyntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax/blob/main/Package.swift) package does:

```swift
func hasEnvironmentVariable(_ name: String) -> Bool {
  return ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment[name] != nil
}

[...]

let buildScriptEnvironment = hasEnvironmentVariable("SWIFT_BUILD_SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT")

[...]

var swiftSyntaxSwiftSettings: [SwiftSetting] = []
var swiftSyntaxBuilderSwiftSettings: [SwiftSetting] = []
var swiftParserSwiftSettings: [SwiftSetting] = []

if buildScriptEnvironment {
  swiftSyntaxSwiftSettings += [
    .define("SWIFTSYNTAX_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS")
  ]
  swiftSyntaxBuilderSwiftSettings += [
    .define("SWIFTSYNTAX_NO_OSLOG_DEPENDENCY")
  ]
}

[...]

    .target(
      name: "SwiftSyntax",
      dependencies: ["SwiftSyntax509", "SwiftSyntax510", "SwiftSyntax511"],
      exclude: ["CMakeLists.txt"],
      swiftSettings: swiftSyntaxSwiftSettings
    )
```