# Swift conditional compilation access control

Tags: ios, swift, access-control, conditional-compilation

I am building an iOS framework and i need the same framework to be used in public apps and in some internal apps , the difference is that in the internal apps I need access to some classes and function that I want to hide from the public apps and i don't want to copy paste code from the framework to the internal apps ...

Is it possible to use conditional compilation (or some other solution **without duplicating code**) to do something like :

```
#if SOMEFLAG
   public
#else
   internal
#endif
   class SomeClass{
       // public when SOMEFLAG otherwise internal
   }
```

of course the code above is not working so it is the pseudo code for what i need ( it doesn't have to be with macros) .

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#ifdef replacement in swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language)

Comment: @Sweeper the link doesn't work for access control, my question is about conditional access control without duplicating code , it doesn't have to be with macros.

Comment: It is not possible to define in that way, Swift Compiler will through the error. How are you planning to distribute the framework.

Comment: I will give the clients the .framework file directly, i don't want to give them the source code.

Comment: @OlegSherman did you get any solution?

Comment: @amar I did not get a solution yet.

Comment: @OlegSherman i am starting to read this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html will let you know if i get a solution.If you get it earlier do let me know