# Change swift class access control based on target

Tags: swift, xcode, xcframework

I have a framework that has some internal source code and we release the compiled framework to users outside of our organization with a very limited public interface.

Some of our internal products need access to more parts of the framework. Is there a way to make classes public when building for one target, but not another?

For example, something like the following:

```swift
#if InternalTarget
public
#endif
class MyClass {

}
```

Comment: [This has been asked before, but there was no answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40522164/5133585)