# Is there any way to check setup while archiving for the AppStore

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store

A question for general improvements of the code. I have an enum with configurations for the app:

```
    enum Configuration
    {
        static let useTestServer = true
        *etc*
    }
```

How can I check that `useTestServer == false` every time I archive the app for the app store? Cause there is always possibility to forget turning test server off while publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use preprocessor macros and check for the existence of the predefined `DEBUG` symbol:

```swift
#if DEBUG
    // TODO: debug build setup
    static let useTestServer = true
#else
    // TODO: release build setup
    static let useTestServer = false
#endif
```

`DEBUG` is typically set to `1` at the target level (Targets > (your target) > Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros > Debug).
This question contains relevant information about preprocessor macros: [#ifdef replacement in the Swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language)
Hope this helps.

Comment: So, I can just use this construction in the AppDelegate to print("Don't use the test server while archiving, mate!") and it will be executed when the build is getting ready?

Comment: #if / #else / #endif are compile-time macros so a print() won't have any effect until the code is actually run.  What you might want to do is write `static let useTestServer = true` in the #if DEBUG block and `static let useTestServer = false` in the #else block.  I edited my answer to clarify.