# Using C macros in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

Have my own macro defined in myProject.pch file,

For example:

```
#define Enable_Analytics
```

And i want to enclose few statements of code at multiple places inside

```
#ifdef Enable_Analytics
  // Code statements which has to executed only if Enable_Analytics is defined
#endif
```

This is useful to include/remove code based on the macro.
In Objective-C this works but in swift i get error. How to use #ifdef in swift?

Comment: Did you have a look at [#ifdef replacement in the Swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-the-swift-language) ?

Comment: @MartinR, yes i have looked at that. I don't want to move that to build settings because I have so many macros like that in my project. If there is no other solution then i will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the C preprocessor on just about and kind of file even if it is not C or a C like language.
It is usually available as `cpp` on most Unix like systems. Just run `cpp your-file.swift` and the C preprocessor should preprocess the file just as it would C.

However I do not know of a way to make the preprocessor use defines within a project file. So you probably will have to manually specify them on the command line like `-DMACRO_NAME=somevalue`.

Alternatively you could `#include` a file containing the defines within each of your swift files and the preprocessor will insert them.

Comment: @MartinR neither does C. The #include directive is part of the C preprocessor. A completely separate and standalone language. The #include will be processed by the preprocessor in the same way as #defines are.