# How do I reference keys/secrets from a file in my project in a Run Script

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Run Script for Fabric/Crashlytics and before I open source my app, I want to put the key/secret in a file like `.env` and reference it in the Run Script so that I can git ignore `.env` and not commit.

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You don't need a Run Script for this; you can inject environment variables in the scheme editor. You retrieve them via NSProcessInfo (now called ProcessInfo in Swift) as I explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344459/341994 Distinguish the environment for _building_ from the environment for _running_.

Comment: I have a Run Script for Fabric/Crashlytics that has a key and secret and I wanted to move them somewhere where I can gitignore them, commit the codebase and not have the general public see my key/secret

Comment: Then this is an x-y question. Ask about your real problem; don't assume some solution and ask about that. However, your scheme is not part of the commit so it seems to me that my previous comment answers this.

Comment: I'll edit. Sorry. Edit: Edited