# How to add bridging header for Dev version and Prod version?

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header, build-variant

I have created two targets of my application i.e Dev and Prod. How can I add bridging header to it for both the version? Is one bridging header is works for both or I have to create two for different targets?

Answer (score 2):

You can add bridging these steps.

Select Target -> Build Settings -> Objective-C Bridging Header -> fill the specified field.

Comment: means I have to add two bridging headers for both the targets?

Comment: Yes, you should add both target.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below to add `Swift Bridging Header` in your project,

1. Add a new file to Xcode `(File > New > File)`, and select `Source` and choose `Header File`
2. Create your file `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`
3. In `Build Settings`, Next to `Objective-C Bridging Header` you need to add the path of your header file. i.e `ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` or `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`.
4. Import your Objective-C classes using `#import <Class Name>`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can use the "#if/#else/#endif" in Bridging Header file.

```
#if DEBUG
     #import "devVersion.h"
#else
     #import "prodVersion.h"
#endif
```

"Now, you must set the "DEBUG" symbol elsewhere, though. Set it in the "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" section, "Other Swift Flags" line. You add the DEBUG symbol with the -D DEBUG entry.
As usual, you can set a different value when in Debug or when in Release."

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152730/3089616

Hope this help!