# Swift NSLog enable based on debugging level

Tags: ios, swift

In Objective C, I have defined various levels of logging by putting this in .pch file:

```
 #ifdef MY_DEBUG  
 #define LOG_LEVEL    2
 #define MyLog(...)     { if(LOG_LEVEL <= 0) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__); }
 #define MyLog1(...)    { if(LOG_LEVEL <= 1) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__); }
 #define MyLog2(...)    { if(LOG_LEVEL <= 2) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__); }
 #define MyLog3(...)    { if(LOG_LEVEL <= 3) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__); }
 #define MyLog4(...)    { if(LOG_LEVEL <= 4) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__); }

 #else
 #define MyLog(...)
 #define MyLog1(...)
 #define MyLog2(...)
 #define MyLog3(...)
 #define MyLog4(...)
 #endif
```

How do I achieve same thing in Swift? Also in Xcode 10.3, I tried defining MY_DEBUG in preprocessor macros for DEBUG version, but it has no effect in my Swift project. What could be wrong?

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslog , it has level of logging support out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
public let kMyLogLevel = 2

#if DEBUG
public func MyLog(text: String)  { if kMyLogLevel <= 0 { NSLog(text) } }
public func MyLog1(text: String) { if kMyLogLevel <= 1 { NSLog(text) } }
public func MyLog2(text: String) { if kMyLogLevel <= 2 { NSLog(text) } }
public func MyLog3(text: String) { if kMyLogLevel <= 3 { NSLog(text) } }
public func MyLog4(text: String) { if kMyLogLevel <= 4 { NSLog(text) } }
public func MyLog5(text: String) { if kMyLogLevel <= 5 { NSLog(text) } }
#else
public func MyLog(text: String)  { }
public func MyLog1(text: String) { }
public func MyLog2(text: String) { }
public func MyLog3(text: String) { }
public func MyLog4(text: String) { }
public func MyLog5(text: String) { }
#endif
```

This can be put in any module at file scope (i.e., not inside a class or other type.)

Note that the input is not a variable argument list, rather a simple text string. The Swift way is to use String interpolation, like so:

```
MyLog("The value is: \(value)")
```

Also, Swift doesn't support preprocessor macros in the same way you're used to with Objective-C. In Swift, you can only provide conditional compilation *flags* and you can only test for existence of those flags (they cannot be assigned a value.) In addition, you cannot create these flags in code (there is no `#define`). These flags must be sent into the compiler's command line (ex: `-DDEBUG`). See the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152730/2203321) for more information.

Swift doesn't provide a `DEBUG` flag by default, you'll need to set that in the build options for your project/target. See the question linked to above for details on this.

The `DEBUG` flag works fine for conditional compilation, but not for your log level. For this, common practice is to use a constant (via the `let` keyword.)

Comment: Ok thanks. How do I define my own debug flag in preprocessor macros in XCode. I defined MY_DEBUG for the Debug version but it has no effect.

Comment: How/where did you define `MY_DEBUG`? And how are you trying to use it?

Comment: There is one problem. I get a crash when I call - MyLog("-[%@ %@] called", NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)), #function)

Comment: How to handle #function in MyLog?

Comment: This solution doesn't directly support variable arguments (`[%@ %@]`). Use string interpolation (as explained in the answer) or use the `String(format:) ` initializer to format the string before passing to `MyLog`.