# Custom TEST pre-processor macros in Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode

In Swift, I can do:

```
#if DEBUG
    // code
#else
    // code
#endif
```

but making custom macros as described in [#ifdef replacement in the Swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-the-swift-language) answers doesn't work for me.

How am I supposed to do this for Swift 5 / Xcode 12?

---

**Edit**:
My problem was that I assumed testing an application would trigger the macros in the application if I defined them in the AppTest target.

Putting `-DYOURMACRO` in *Other Swift Flags* under *Swift Compiler - Custom Flags* does indeed work.

The way to do what I wanted is either to put this flag in the application target whenever I want to run unit tests (really don't like this solution), or using launch arguments instead (not optimal but will do).

Comment: It works on my  Xcode 12.5, what version are you really targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, Objective-C and Metal you have to use `#ifdef DEBUG` (Xcode 12.5):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
    BOOL const DEBUG_BUILD = YES;
#else
    BOOL const DEBUG_BUILD = NO;
#endif
```

But in Swift you have to use just the following syntax (Xcode 12.5):

```
import Foundation

#if DEBUG
    let debugBuild: Bool = true
#else
    let debugBuild: Bool = false
#endif
```

And why you said you couldn't use a custom pre-processor macros?

```
#if !RELEASE
    import SceneKit
#endif

func loader() {
    #if DEBUG
        SceneKit.SCNSphere.init(radius: 0.1)
    #endif
}
```