# My app crashes on device but works on simulator iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, crash-reports

My app is crashing after my login page on my physical device but it has no issues on the xCode simulator. I have been trying to debug for hours with suggestions I saw online and nothing is working.

```
**Crash logs:**
Incident Identifier: 89F8B664-0E56-458F-9DBC-4680F6BAD3AC
CrashReporter Key:   216037edb6b5b01363303754d6b506f699263e00
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,5
Process:             Moonlight [26102]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F26FF432-36B2-4302-B0A9-95F7B6DEEF0D/Moonlight.app/Moonlight
Identifier:          com.danya.swift.Moonlight
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.danya.swift.Moonlight [1879]

Date/Time:           2023-02-22 02:27:54.6242 +0300
Launch Time:         2023-02-22 02:27:38.7167 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.3 (20D47)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.40.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104355224
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [26102]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Moonlight                              0x104355224 InstagramApi.().init() + 312
1   Moonlight                              0x104355200 InstagramApi.().init() + 276
2   Moonlight                              0x1043550d8 one-time initialization function for shared + 36
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4ce8f88 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4cea7d4 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
5   Moonlight                              0x10438be60 ProfileTableViewController.init(coder:) + 1132
6   Moonlight                              0x10438be84 @objc ProfileTableViewController.init(coder:) + 32
7   UIKitCore                              0x1bfb9433c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 1544
8   UIFoundation                           0x1c7b31390 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 668
9   UIFoundation                           0x1c7b3158c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1176
10  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b32d00 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 316
11  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb93cc4 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsAndTrackChildViewControllerIndexWithParent:forKey:] + 188
12  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb93564 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1116
13  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb92cd0 -[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 92
14  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb9433c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 1544
15  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b31390 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 668
16  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b3158c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1176
17  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b32d00 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 316
18  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb93cc4 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsAndTrackChildViewControllerIndexWithParent:forKey:] + 188
19  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb93564 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1116
20  UIKitCore                              0x1bfcb4bd8 -[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 80
21  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb9433c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 1544
22  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b31390 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 668
23  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b32d00 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 316
24  UIKitCore                              0x1bfc56218 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 92
25  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b31390 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 668
26  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b3158c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1176
27  UIFoundation                           0x1c7b32d00 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 316
28  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb944d0 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 292
29  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb33724 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 760
30  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb32140 -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 236
31  UIKitCore                              0x1bfb31f7c -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 80
32  libswiftUIKit.dylib                    0x1c626a5d0 UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController<A>(identifier:creator:) + 248
33  Moonlight                              0x10437cc64 closure #1 in WelcomeViewController.loginButtonPressed(_:) + 360
34  Moonlight                              0x104369f9c closure #1 in static FUser.loginUserWith(email:password:completion:) + 336
35  Moonlight                              0x10436a018 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed FIRAuthDataResult?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 76
36  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4ce7460 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
37  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4ce8f88 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
38  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4cf77f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
39  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4cf7444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
40  CoreFoundation                         0x1bd7616c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
41  CoreFoundation                         0x1bd74302c __CFRunLoopRun + 2036
42  CoreFoundation                         0x1bd747eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
43  GraphicsServices                       0x1f793d368 GSEventRunModal + 164
44  UIKitCore                              0x1bfc3d668 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
45  UIKitCore                              0x1bfc3d2cc UIApplicationMain + 340
46  libswiftUIKit.dylib                    0x1c626a308 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 104
47  Moonlight                              0x10434b344 main + 108
48  dyld                                   0x1dc040960 start + 2528

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e4da8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1f7a1c mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1f7c5c mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e52ec mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1bd741ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1bd742d08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1bd747eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x1b7a7c054 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x1b7a7bf3c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9   UIKitCore                              0x1bfd726a4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 436
10  Foundation                             0x1b7a95518 __NSThread__start__ + 716
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b9496cc _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e4da8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1f7a1c mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1f7c5c mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e52ec mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1bd741ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1bd742d08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1bd747eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CFNetwork                              0x1beab2ff0 0x1be85b000 + 2457584
8   Foundation                             0x1b7a95518 __NSThread__start__ + 716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b9496cc _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:   Dispatch queue: com.google.firebase.firestore.rpc
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e8494 poll + 8
1   grpc                                   0x106801d24 pollset_work(grpc_pollset*, grpc_pollset_worker**, long long) + 1276
2   grpc                                   0x106803ba0 pollset_work(grpc_pollset*, grpc_pollset_worker**, long long) + 72
3   grpc                                   0x1067e701c cq_next(grpc_completion_queue*, gpr_timespec, void*) + 320
4   grpcpp                                 0x106183fbc grpc::CompletionQueue::AsyncNextInternal(void**, bool*, gpr_timespec) + 60
5   FirebaseFirestore                      0x105655b68 firebase::firestore::remote::Datastore::PollGrpcQueue() + 104
6   FirebaseFirestore                      0x1057759f0 firebase::firestore::util::Task::ExecuteAndRelease() + 184
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4ce8f88 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4cf0640 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4cf118c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c4cfbe10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948b98 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e567c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b95006c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   grpc                                   0x1068ed3f4 gpr_cv_wait + 124
3   grpc                                   0x106805ef0 grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) + 180
4   grpc                                   0x1068f8328 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b9496cc _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e567c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b95006c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   grpc                                   0x1068ed3f4 gpr_cv_wait + 124
3   grpc                                   0x106805ef0 grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) + 180
4   grpc                                   0x1068f8328 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b9496cc _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fb1e567c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b95006c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   grpc                                   0x1068ed3e4 gpr_cv_wait + 108
3   grpc                                   0x1068fc24c timer_thread(void*) + 552
4   grpc                                   0x1068f8328 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b9496cc _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20b948ba4 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x0000000214e1bf78   x3: 0x0000000280e68e00
    x4: 0x0000000000000063   x5: 0x0000000000000041   x6: 0x0000000000000072   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000dc0  x11: 0x00000000000007fb
   x12: 0x00000000a3603893  x13: 0x00000000000007fd  x14: 0x00000000a3804038  x15: 0x00000000a3603893
   x16: 0x0000000214e1bf48  x17: 0x60f0000214e1bf48  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000283015d50
   x20: 0x000000016bab83e0  x21: 0x0000000280e69bc0  x22: 0xc000000000000024  x23: 0x4000000280e69bc0
   x24: 0x00000001b9303e19  x25: 0x0000000000000002  x26: 0x00000001045d2000  x27: 0x0000000000000468
   x28: 0x00000001045d7000   fp: 0x000000016bab8420   lr: 0x0000000104355200
    sp: 0x000000016bab83e0   pc: 0x0000000104355224 cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x00000001043550b4  esr: 0xf2000001 (Breakpoint) brk 1

Binary Images:
       0x104344000 -        0x104583fff Moonlight arm64  <6dafd094a824333fb825b7dcedfc5dc3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F26FF432-36B2-4302-B0A9-95F7B6DEEF0D/Moonlight.app/Moonlight
       0x1c4ce5000 -        0x1c4d2bfff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <ded4d0a5142032ae83a6c31d938a1c9a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1bf89c000 -        0x1c108ffff UIKitCore arm64e  <cf21ad9cefbf3961a7c054bd30cefea9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x1c7b23000 -        0x1c7c5afff UIFoundation arm64e  <22746b0a15463d81ae08ee0f17206e53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
       0x1c6235000 -        0x1c62a9fff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64e  <ed49edbf22363545afc1e4cf7a29aff2> /usr/lib/swift/libswiftUIKit.dylib
       0x1bd6c7000 -        0x1bdaacfff CoreFoundation arm64e  <42ccfc7bff323d258f01ccb2ad843a8b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1f793c000 -        0x1f7944fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <85419099269b336d86b40d52d0ff6923> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x1dc02b000 -        0x1dc0ae093 dyld arm64e  <4b042f280d1430eca1de3dbb10866ad7> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x20b948000 -        0x20b953fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <45ac734e66493ee2a0963fd66441ab78> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1fb1e4000 -        0x1fb21bfeb libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <c76e6bed463530c68f19fb829bbe1ae1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1b7a3a000 -        0x1b8383fff Foundation arm64e  <e5f615c7cc5e3656860041c767812a35> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1be85b000 -        0x1bec24fff CFNetwork arm64e  <7f3313c9143533338c82dc961429d0b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
       0x10677c000 -        0x106a33fff grpc arm64  <57469164f14331889e44974a12e36384> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F26FF432-36B2-4302-B0A9-95F7B6DEEF0D/Moonlight.app/Frameworks/grpc.framework/grpc
       0x10616c000 -        0x1061c7fff grpcpp arm64  <12eec987bb2939488c9f33900bd54816> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F26FF432-36B2-4302-B0A9-95F7B6DEEF0D/Moonlight.app/Frameworks/grpcpp.framework/grpcpp
       0x105628000 -        0x105847fff FirebaseFirestore arm64  <e766689ebf0936a0aea7116cdb5e6cb2> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F26FF432-36B2-4302-B0A9-95F7B6DEEF0D/Moonlight.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestore.framework/FirebaseFirestore

EOF
```

I have looked at all the suggestions on other stack questions and nothing works. Please help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-crashes-from-swift-runtime-errors

Comment: I still cannot pin point where the app is crashing from

Comment: one of the reason can be memory overflow. when you are using simulator, it uses your Mac's ram which is too much, but when it comes to real devices, depends on what device you use, your device's ram which is limited and causes crashes.

Comment: I actually found that it is a problem with release mode. It is working on my phone now in debug mode, but crashes in release mode

Comment: You probably need to look thru the differences between the modes, at the project *and* target level, to compare in Xcode. Also remember if settings point to something (esp. different files, there could be problems at that level).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same crash. Sharing in case this helps. In my case, the crash began happening after I created a 2nd scheme and corresponding target to my project. I had started using environment variables to designate my Prod vs Dev app.

For example, I added:

`Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment Variables: [Name: environment, Value: dev]`

and then referenced them in the AppDelegate  using: `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["environment"] == “dev”`

to tell the app which config file to use.

This works when built directly from Xcode, but it fails when built on device because these environment variables are not available when a user launches the app on their device. Because these do not work in that case, my build path was null and it was crashing before the app launched. It would show the launch screen and then pop.

So I guess it’s worth looking if you have environment variables set in your scheme for this purpose and consider replacing them with “Swift Compiler - Custom Flags” in your Build Settings for each target similar to Daniel’s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-the-swift-language/24152730#24152730).